# Naming FFMpeg output file after Container Conversion

Tags: ffmpeg, containers, filenames

I repackage .mkv and .avi to .mp4 using this command.

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for %%a in ( "*.mkv" "*.avi" ) do (
(ffmpeg -i "%%a" -c:v copy -c:a copy -y "%%a.mp4"))
```

The problem is my output files get named filename.mkv.mp4 or filename.avi.mp4  How do I declude the .mkv/.avi part?

I've found a batch file that finds filenames containing any keyboard key or combination and removes them, which I provide for anyone who needs to remove/replace characters appearing anywhere in a filename.

I use this batch file to remove the .mkv, .avi which appear anywhere in the filename.  But.. a space is left in place of .mkv.  I recently found the fix for removing the .mkv not leaving a space, which is at the bottom.

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%N in (`dir /s /b`) do 
(
set var=%%~nN
set var=!var:^.mkv= !
set var=!var:%%= !

if not "!var!"=="%%~nN" (
  if not exist "%%~dpN!var!%%~xN" (
      echo "%%N" --^> "!var!%%~xN"
      ren "%%N" "!var!%%~xN"
    ) else (
      echo File "!var!%%~xN" ^(from %%N^) already 
exists.
    )
  )
)
```

To remove .mkv and not replace it with a space, all that I had to do was to remove the space right before the first occurrence of explanation point.
By the way, this file will not remove the last period in a file name.  Also, if you want to delete more keyboard keys, then add more lines right below them. Two lines for each thing you want removed. You can use any keyboard character.  For example, to remove .mkv not leaving a space; and, replace all & with a space, use:

```
set var=!var:^.mkv=!
set var=!var:%%= !
set var=!var:^&= !
set var=!var:%%= !
```

Finally, I didn't write this script but since I did not document it's originator, I don't want to take credit for its authenticity.